# How do I extract object elements to populate in an array as single element

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

With the following code, I am able to get data that is saved in the local storage:

```
this.order = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('order'));
```

Now, the order variable looks like the following if I console.log it:

```
[
  {id: 1, title: 'Title 1'},
  {id: 2, title: 'Title 2'},
]
```

How can I create an array that simply stores the id's of order array in VueJs or JavaScript?

As an end result, I want to have an array like this:

```
newArray = [1,2];
```

I tried the following:

```
for(var i = 0; i<=this.order.length; i++){
    this.newArray.push(this.order[i]);
}
console.log(this.newArray);
```

When I look in the console it gives me undefined.

What is the right approach for me to have an array like the one shown below?

```
newArray = [1,2];
```

Comment: I honestly don't see why someone downvoted my question. There is a word called suggestion and a button named edit which available to users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the original array and extract the `id` from each element:

```
let newArray = this.order.map(x => x.id);
```